# OBIEE 11g: white space character

Tags: oracle, whitespace, obiee

The problem: Direct SQL based OBIEE analysis ignores whitespace character.

For example: 
Oracle: `select chr(9)||'New volume' from dual`
Oracle result: "   New volume"
OBIEE result: "New volume" (ignores chr(9))

Why OBIEE ignores chr(9) code showing result? 
Should I use some specific HTML codes? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Total goal is to change text alignment for some values of OBI table analysis. I tried to format some table values using OBI settingsm but it works for the whole table. Maybe I should use CSS formatting? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested your statement in obiee 12c , it also ignores statement with leading whitespaces. but when you execute this. it does include it on the answers and export file ...

```
select 'test'|| chr(9)||'New volume' as c1 from dual
```

Do you need to add whitespace to the start always ? Whats the total goal , so maybe we can find alternative workaround for your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

OBI trims leading spaces and trailing spaces from strings. What's the goal of this? If you're using Direct DB requests then that points to a questionable usage of the tool already.